# Finding the array length of a two dimensional array using a nested while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, nested-loops

I can't seem to get the array length through a nested while loop. The rows and cols can be any value but I need to verify that they equal the array length. array length = rows*cols

A nested for loop wouldn't help me because I don't know how long the array entered might be.

```
void add(char arr[][SIZE], int rows, int cols, int val) {
    int arrayStorage = 0;
    int arrayStorage2 = 0;

    while (arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2] != 0 && (isalpha(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || isdigit(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2] == ' ') && (isprint(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || !(iscntrl(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]))))
    {
        arrayStorage2 = 0;
        while (arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2] != 0 && (isalpha(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || isdigit(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2] == ' ') && (isprint(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]) || !(iscntrl(arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2]))))
        {
            arrayStorage2++;

        }
        arrayStorage2--;
        arrayStorage++;
    }

        int storage3 = (arrayStorage2) * arrayStorage;
        cout << storage3;
        char addVal = (char)val;
      if (( storage3 == (rows * cols)) && rows > 0 && rows <= SIZE && cols > 0 && cols <= SIZE)
          {
         // do stuff
          }

}

int main()
{
    char arr4 [][SIZE] = {{'a','b','c',' ',' '}, {'d','e','f',' ',' '}, {'g','r','o','w','n'}, {'n','o','w',' ',' '}};
    add(arr4,4,5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

storage3 the array length is 5 when it is supposed to be 20

Comment: Why are you testing for 0 in `add`?  Accesses out of bounds will give undefined results.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? There's no way to determine the length of an array if you're only given a pointer to the first element thereof (which is what `arr` is).

Comment: @stark I am not?

Comment: There must be some way to find the length of the array?

Comment: `arr` is not an array, it's a pointer. If it was an actual array you could simply do `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` but since `arr` is a pointer it will not give you the correct result.

Comment: you have to pass 'size' into your function as well as the pointer 'arr', consider using 'std::vector' if it is possible in your assignment

Comment: So it is impossible to find the size of the elements of the pointer?

Comment: You already know the size.  It is `rows * cols`

Comment: `while (arr[arrayStorage][arrayStorage2] != 0` <- testing for 0.

Comment: @melpomene isn't it testing for null in c++?

Comment: `arr[...][...]` is a `char`. What do you mean by "null"?

Comment: @melpomene a null value as in no values are in that index

Comment: There is no such thing.

Comment: @Amaterasu Use `vector` they're much easier than arrays. You obviously have little idea what arrays are like in C++, vectors are much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be not to loop at all!
change the type used as the array. If instead of `char arr[][]` you define a type that wraps around the array and exposes its dimensions. Something like:

```
template <int tRows, int tCols>
class Array2d
{
public:
     static constexpr int sRows = tRows;
     static constexpr int sCols = tCols;
     char mArr[tRows][tCols]
};
```

Then you can make your add function a template function and use the exposed dimensions in your check

```
template <class Array_t>
void add(Array_t& arr, int rows, int cols)
{
     int storage3 = Array_t::sRows * Array_t::sCols;
     if (( storage3 == (rows * cols)) && rows > 0 && rows <= SIZE && cols > 0 && cols <= SIZE)
     {
          // do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the method header, is there any way around that? Also what is constexpr?

Comment: In which case there isn't really a way that you can find the dimensions inside your function. your variable `char arr[][]` is basically just a pointer to the first byte in a block of memory. Unless you reserve the final element for some special value and check for that value, you cannot know when you have reached the end of your allocated memory. This is also risky, you'd need to be sure that your memory is initialized and that your special _end of allocated memory_ value could never be used as valid entry to the array

Comment: `constexpr` tells the compiler that the statement can be determined at compile time. That means that in this case, wherever the compiler sees `Array_t::sRows` it can optimize it very well because it knows already what the value of `Array_t::sRows` will be

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I appreciate your time and effort